# files are uploaded as user apache

Tags: php, apache

hello today i have a problem

[image]

**how can this happen ? everything that is generated from php goes with a user apache.**
is it php fault ? or its an server fault ? it should be 'ausername' rather then apache.

Thanks for looking in.

Adam Ramadhan

Comment: apache is also a user and php run into apache user as default

Comment: If the user that runs php is apache then it looks logic. Either try to fix this or run some chown command after upload, this should do it.

Comment: You can change the default in httpd.conf via the User and Group settings

Comment: @Mark sounds like a worthy answer?

Comment: I'm more worried about the umask for your apache user, look at the permissions, they're 755, you might want to tighten that down a bit, unless there's an explicit need for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless PHP is run through FastCGI with suexec uploaded files or any file created by a PHP script will belong to the user that executed the script, apache in this case. If the server is running `mod_php` you can't get around this. Unless you change the user and group that runs the httpd process.

So neither PHP or Apache is at fault, this is how it's configured.

Also, this question belongs to serverfault.com.

Comment: thanks!, yes i thought its a php problem so i posted here. thankyou.